# Proving the convergence of a recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the following sequence, defined recursively: $$ x_{n+1}=\frac{2x_n^3+2}{3x_n^2} $$ Prove that $x_n$ converges to  $ 2^{1/3} $ and  $ x_7 $ approximates $ \root 3 \of2 $ accurately to 6 decimal places.

I'm completely clueless here, can this be done without a calculator ? Help would be really appreciated, thank you for your time !

Comment: I guess I will need $x_0$

Comment: This is the complete text.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence is derived from an application of [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) for $f(x) = x^3 - 2$. So clearly it'd converge to the real root $\sqrt[3]{2}$, given you choose an appropriate value for $x_0$:
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n -\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}=x_n-\frac{x_n^3-2}{3x_n^2 }=\frac{2-x_n^3+3x_n^3}{3x_n^2 }=\frac{2x_n^3+2}{3x_n^2}
$$

For the second part you should find a relationship between successive error terms: $\epsilon_{n} = |x_n - \sqrt[3]{2}|$, and take the logarithm of $\epsilon_7$ to find how close it is.

Comment: Wow, the Newton's method part was really cool, how did you even think of that ?! Anyway, could you explain a bit more the part about the error ? I don't think I get it yet

Comment: My intuition for the second part was that if the number is say 1.259921x... then if we subtract the actual number from it ($\sqrt[3]{2} = 1.2599210498948732...$), we'd notice that it becomes (0.000...y...) (x,y are some arbitrary numbers). We'd call that thing with lots of zeros in front the error term. So if we take the logarithm it'd tell us how many zero's there are before the first significant figure. I'm still working on the relationship between error terms though.

Comment: @JamesHarrison - what a flash of inspiration! would this approach or a variant of it be applicable to most if not all cases of recursive sequences?